# Overflow: auto not working or working inconsistently on Android

Tags: android, cordova, overflow

I'm trying to use `overflow: auto` in a PhoneGap app on Android, but the scrolling frequently does not work: on Android 4.1 it occasionally sticks; on Android 4.3, items will generally scroll one time (not necessarily the first time), and then never again.

The CSS I'm using to apply overflow is:

```
.overthrow {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I was using filamentgroup's overthrow library, but as we are no longer supporting versions of Android/iOS that do not (nominally) support `overflow: auto`, we're no longer using it.

The scrollable areas work perfectly on iOS and in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

```
.overthrow {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border :1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```